# Finding tuple inside an array and get its index and value

Tags: numpy, tuples, numpy-ndarray

I have an array like this

```
np.array([[(115, 1), 47],
       [(115, 2), 1],
       [(115, 3), 3],
       [(2147482888, 5), 26],
       [(275030867, 5), 3]], dtype=object)
```

> How do i get a desired tuple say (115, 1) and get its corresponding
> value 47 and update it with addition or subtraction based on certain
> conditions.

> Lets say i want to get (115, 1) and add 2 to its value 47 + 2 if the array contains (115, 1)

> If array does not contain (10009, 10) then add it to the array with default values say 10

Thanks

Comment: this is the wrong data structure.  You maybe want a dict, but not an array

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are best used for contiguous blocks of homogenous data (n-array of floats for example).  It sounds like you want a dict which is key-value pairs.  In that case, you can do the following:

```
# original data
x = np.array([[(115, 1), 47],
       [(115, 2), 1],
       [(115, 3), 3],
       [(2147482888, 5), 26],
       [(275030867, 5), 3],
       [0, 0]], dtype=object)

d = dict(x)
d[(115,1)] += 2
```

output:

```
{(115, 1): 49,
 (115, 2): 1,
 (115, 3): 3,
 (2147482888, 5): 26,
 (275030867, 5): 3,
 0: 0}
```

Comment: i am currently using default dict but its too memory consuming for searching a key and updating it.
I  thought using numpy array would reduce the memory

Comment: how big is the dictionary?  And how will it be used?  You may consider a database (postgres) if you don't have enough memory.

Comment: 80 million keys and values

Comment: ah.  You're running out of memory with a defaultdict?

Comment: So only use dict rather than defaultdict ? Is there no way solve through numpy ?
I can change my array structure too rather than having tuple array can get as [[115,1,47]] also

Answer (score 0):

Fast and compact only applies to numeric numpy arrays.  With object dtype, speeds and storage are similar to lists (and maybe even slower).

```
In [39]: arr =np.array([[(115, 1), 47],
    ...:        [(115, 2), 1],
    ...:        [(115, 3), 3],
    ...:        [(2147482888, 5), 26],
    ...:        [(275030867, 5), 3]], dtype=object)
In [40]: arr.shape
Out[40]: (5, 2)
```

One plus to such an array is that it's easy to access 'columns':

```
In [41]: arr[:,0]
Out[41]: 
array([(115, 1), (115, 2), (115, 3), (2147482888, 5), (275030867, 5)],
      dtype=object)
In [42]: arr[:,1]
Out[42]: array([47, 1, 3, 26, 3], dtype=object)
```

The whole array as a list of lists:

```
In [43]: alist = arr.tolist()
In [44]: alist
Out[44]: 
[[(115, 1), 47],
 [(115, 2), 1],
 [(115, 3), 3],
 [(2147482888, 5), 26],
 [(275030867, 5), 3]]
```

But for finding a tuple, it's easier to work with a list of the tuples:

```
In [47]: alist = arr[:,0].tolist()
In [48]: alist
Out[48]: [(115, 1), (115, 2), (115, 3), (2147482888, 5), (275030867, 5)]
In [49]: alist.index((115,1))
Out[49]: 0
In [50]: alist.index((115,3))
Out[50]: 2
In [51]: arr[2,:]
Out[51]: array([(115, 3), 3], dtype=object)
```

That said, your structure, and desired actions do look at lot more like dictionary actions.  Finding 'keys' and adding them is not a natural fit for `numpy`.